# Flutter: LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'user' has not been initialized.)

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am nit sure about this error because user should be inithialized in Auth Provider and then I will be able to use it in User Provider but flutter continue giving this error.

Here is my code. Can someone help to solve or tell me a better form to organize it?

**AuthProvider**

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  late final FirebaseAuth _auth;
  late final NavigationService _navigationService;
  late final DatabaseService _databaseService;

  late UserData user;
  AuthProvider() {
    _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    _navigationService = GetIt.instance.get<NavigationService>();
    _databaseService = GetIt.instance<DatabaseService>();
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((_user) {
      if (_user != null) {
        //_databaseService.updateUserLastSeenTime(_user.uid);
        _databaseService.getUser(_user.uid).then(
          (_snapshot) {
            if (_snapshot.exists) {
              if (_snapshot.data() != null) {
                user =
                    UserData.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(_snapshot.data())));
                notifyListeners();
              }
            }
            _navigationService.removeAndNavigateToRoute('/home');
          },
        );
      } else {
        _navigationService.removeAndNavigateToRoute('/login');
      }
    });
  }
```

**User Provider**

```
class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final DatabaseService _databaseService = DatabaseService();

  UserData _user = AuthProvider().user;
  UserData get getUser => _user;

  Future<void> refreshUser() async {
    UserData user = await _databaseService.getUserDetails();
    _user = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }

// update user name
  Future<void> editName(String name) async {
    try {
      await _databaseService.getUserDoc(_user.uid).update({'name': name});
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
    }
  }

// update user last name
  Future<void> editLastName(String lastName) async {
    try {
      await _databaseService
          .getUserDoc(_user.uid)
          .update({'lastName': lastName});
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be rather self-describing. The "user" variable has not been initialized. What makes you think it should have?

Comment: I supose 'user' variable was inizialized because whein I log in I create it in Auth Provider

Comment: Well, the AuthProvider constructor contains async code that is not finished when the constructor is done. It is very likely that the user variable is not initialized in that case.

Comment: Can u explain me why AuthProvider is asyc? I have wroted it following a tutorial and I can't udertand it completely.

Comment: Well, it uses `listen` and `then`, both methods that do not trigger immediately, but instead call the given callback when it is time to do so. So the code you have in your constructor will *not* run when your constructor is called. Your constructor just sets it up to be called at a later time.

Comment: oh! I think I can start from ur commrnt. Thankyou very much for the explanation!